# Page not responding on IIS 7

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have a report. It's getting more records and make .csv file and display records on browser.

It's not responding every time but sometime it's responding.

Comment: show your code and be more specific.

Comment: If i have provided limit for 100 records. it's working fine so, My code is correct. but when i have executed my hole query then one thing is csv file made on server but it's not responseing.

Comment: Daniel, its not going to be responsive if you call too many records on a single page. You will have to try pagination or some filter on the search for limiting the query. but yes seeing your code might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It may memory issue please release all control which are not used for long
>   time. and make sure all connection are close if not necessary.